# Copy & Paste in Vista / Explorer broken (not MS-VPC)

Tags: windows-vista, windows-explorer

On vista copy & paste has recently stopped working in "explorer" or whatever the hell they call their file manager, it is limited to only files / directories, copying text/graphics/random junk between apps works just fine. I do use MS Virtual PC, but the issue persists between clean boots.

I am using total commander as a stop-gap atm, but its not ideal.

nothing odd was installed recently, I have run a full scan on AVG & windows defender, uninstalled a load of junk that had been kicking around for a while, killing the explorer.exe processes & restarting them makes no difference also.

When "cutting" a file, the icon goes semi transparent, then when pasting the cursor changes to the busy circle thing for a couple of frames, then reverts to the normal pointer...

Any clue where to start looking for the problem? I would really rather not re-install, but it is looking inevitable atm, so go ahead & save my weekend!

Comment: try to disable clipboard integration services of virtual pc...

(If you connect to your guest via RDP, make sure that not **both** VPC and RDP have clipboard integration enabled. For a test, disable both first.)

Comment: Do **Ctrl+C** and **Ctrl+v** work in total commander? Because these commands are done via Explorer, not internally by total commander.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [this tool](http://windowsxp.mvps.org/temp/GetOpenClipboardWindow.zip) (found in [this thread](http://www.howtofixcomputers.com/bb/ftopic140408.html)).  It will display if any application has a "lock" on the clipboard.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried using the keyboard shortcuts of crtl-v, ctrl-c, and ctrl-x?

does right click hold and drag move?

instead of using total commander, try free commander...you will like it more, and ditch explorer and total comander.

Answer (score 0):

Try re-registering shell32.dll to rule out a glitch with the shell itself.

1. Click **Start**
2. Click **Run**
3. Type **regsvr32 /i shell32.dll** and click **OK**
4. Restart

See if you have any joy following that.